# How to generate configuration for combination of multiple environments and mutations

Tags: go, configuration, config, go-templates, gomplate

I'm trying to use gomplate as a generator of configuration. The problem I'm facing now is having multiple mutations and environments where the application needs to be configured in a different way. I'd like to achieve some user-friendly and readable way with the least possible repetitions in the template and source data.

The motivation behind this is to have generated source data `app_config` which can be used in a following gomplate as following:

```
feature_a={{ index (datasource "app_config").features.feature_a .Env.APP_MUTATION .Env.ENV_NAME | required }}
feature_b={{ index (datasource "app_config").features.feature_b .Env.APP_MUTATION .Env.ENV_NAME | required }}
```

Basically I'd like to have this source data

```yaml
features:
    feature_a:
        ~: true
    feature_b:
        mut_a:
            ~: false
            dev: true
            test: true
        mut_b:
            ~: true
```

converted into this result (used as `app_config` gomplate datasource)

```yaml
features:
    feature_a:
        mut_a:
            dev: true
            test: true
            load: true
            staging: true
            prod: true
        mut_b:
            dev: true
            test: true
            load: true
            staging: true
            prod: true
    feature_b:
        mut_a:
            dev: true
            test: true
            load: false
            staging: false
            prod: false
        mut_b:
            dev: true
            test: true
            load: true
            staging: true
            prod: true
```

given that datasource `platform` is defined as

```yaml
mutations:
    - mut_a
    - mut_b
environments:
    - dev
    - test
    - load
    - staging
    - prod
```

I chose to use the `~` to state that every environment or mutation that is not defined will get the value behind `~`.
This should work under assumption that the lowest level is environment and the level before the lowest is mutation. Unless environments are not defined, in that case mutation level is lowest and applies for all mutations and environments. However I know this brings extra complexity, so I'm wiling to use simplified variant where mutations are always defined:

```yaml
features:
    feature_a:
        mut_a: true
        mut_b: true
    feature_b:
        mut_a:
            ~: false
            dev: true
            test: true
        mut_b:
            ~: true
```

However, since I'm fairly new to gomplate, I'm not sure whether it is the right tool for the job.
I welcome every feedback.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I decided that this issue will be better solved with separate tool.